# Is there an easy and effecient way to code jumping and gravity logic in python using pygame for a platformer?

Tags: python, pygame

Im making a platformer in python using pygame, but i am stuck on the collision, jumping and gravity logic, i figured out the collision logic but not the gravity and jumping. So im asking someone to make a example for my code, because im stuck on this for about 3 weeks now.

Project File: https://github.com/1NilusNilus/Pygame-Platformer

Code:

```
import pygame
import os
import sys


class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get(self):
        with open(self.path, "r") as file:

            data = file.read()
            data = data.split("\n")

            return data

class Tile(object):

    def __init__(self, screen, level):
        self.screen = screen
        self.level = level
        self.sprites = {
                        "dirt": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/entit/Desktop/Python/Platformer/img/dirt.png"),
                        "grass": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/entit/Desktop/Python/Platformer/img/grass.png"),
                        "brick": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/entit/Desktop/Python/Platformer/img/brick.png")
                        }

        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.size = [30,30]
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(self.pos, self.size)
        self.tiles = []

    def testCollision(self, player_rect):
        hitlist = []
        for tile in self.tiles:
            if player_rect.colliderect(tile):
                hitlist.append(tile)
        return hitlist

    def draw(self):
        self.pos[0] = 0
        self.pos[1] = 0

        for tiles in self.level:
            self.pos[0] = 0

            for tile in tiles:

                if tile == "1":
                    self.screen.blit(self.sprites["dirt"], self.pos)
                    self.tiles.append(pygame.Rect(self.pos, self.size))

                if tile == "2":
                    self.screen.blit(self.sprites["grass"], self.pos)
                    self.tiles.append(pygame.Rect(self.pos, self.size))

                if tile == "3":
                    self.screen.blit(self.sprites["brick"], self.pos)
                    self.tiles.append(pygame.Rect(self.pos, self.size))

                self.pos[0] += self.size[0]
            self.pos[1] += self.size[1]


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, screen, tile, sprite):
        self.screen = screen
        self.sprite = sprite

        self.tile = tile

        self.vel = [0, 0]
        self.acc = [0.1, 0.1]
        self.pos = [180, 390]
        self.size = self.sprite.get_size()
        self.player_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(self.pos, self.size)

        self.dir = {"right":False, "left":False}

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.sprite, self.pos)

    def move(self):
        self.collision_types = {"left":False, "right":False, "top":False, "bottom":False}

        self.player_rect.x = self.pos[0]
        self.player_rect.y = self.pos[1]

        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]

        for tile in self.tile.testCollision(self.player_rect):
            if self.vel[0] > 0:
                self.vel[0] = 0
                self.pos[0] = tile.left - self.size[0]
                self.collision_types["right"] = True

            if self.vel[0] < 0:
                self.vel[0] = 0
                self.pos[0] = tile.right
                self.collision_types["left"] = True

        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]

        for tile in self.tile.testCollision(self.player_rect):
            if self.vel[1] > 0:
                self.pos[1] = tile.top - self.size[1]
                self.collision_types["bottom"] = True
                self.vel[1] = 0

            if self.vel[1] < 0:
                self.pos[1] = tile.bottom
                self.collision_types["top"] = True

        if self.dir["left"]:
            self.vel[0] = -2

        elif self.dir["right"]:
            self.vel[0] = 2

        else:
            self.vel[0] = 0


class Game:

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.FPS = 60
        self.running = True
        self.bgcolor = (66,135,245)

        self.level = Level("C:/UserS/entit/Desktop/Python/Platformer/level.txt").get()
        self.tile = Tile(self.screen, self.level)
        self.player = Player(self.screen, self.tile, pygame.image.load("C:/UserS/entit/Desktop/Python/Platformer/img/player.png"))

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.player.dir["left"] = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.player.dir["left"] = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.player.dir["right"] = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.player.dir["right"] = False


    def update(self):
        self.player.move()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bgcolor)

        self.tile.draw()
        self.player.draw()

        pygame.display.update()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.clock.tick(self.FPS)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


def main():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()

    screen_size = [720,480]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("platformer")

    game = Game(screen)
    game.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the gravity logic is straight forward. Gravity is acceleration so it increases the vertical velocity toward the ground. In a pygame screen, positive Y is down, so gravity increases the Y velocity. For the jump, you just set the Y velocity to a negative number (up) and let gravity do the rest.

Only a few changes are needed:

In the Player class:

```
def __init__(self, screen, tile, sprite):
    self.gravity = .1  # gravity acceleration  # add this line
    self.screen = screen
    self.sprite = sprite
    .........

def move(self):
    self.vel[1] += self.gravity   # adjust vertical velocity  # add this line
    self.collision_types = {"left":False, "right":False, "top":False, "bottom":False}
    .........
```

In the Game class:

```
def events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:  # player jump   # add this line
            self.player.vel[1] = -5  # add this line
        ........
```

Note that with the jump added, the player can collide with a platform from the side or bottom while the player X and Y velocities are both non-zero. You will need to update the collision logic for this.